# How to save a List View in settings? UWP C#

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, settings

**I have an editable List View that I wanted to save into UWP application's settings and load on the start of the app, so that the changes are always saved.**

The problem is that ListViews cannot be added directly into settings and I couldn't find a complete solution for saving them, despite doing some research.

- When converting with Binary Formatter an Exception is thrown that the list is not serializable.
- When converting with JSON a Stack Overflow exception is thrown
- Other ways are not described completely (someone wrote how to save but didn't write how to load)

**Which solution for saving a ListView in settings is the best and how to implement it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you could not save a listview directly into settings. A possible way is save some key values of the ListView into local files. When you load the app, read these value from local files, and set to the listview.

You could refer to this: [Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: So I understand that it's not possible to save full custom ListView items in a file? In other questions there are answers that you can use BinaryFormatter, JSONconvert etc.. Does this mean that they somehow 'don't support' ListViews?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to directly save the full listview control